# Interpolate missing values when joining two tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, window-functions, recursive-query, gaps-and-islands

I have two tables of different density data and I'd like to be able to join them but interpolate this values in the lower frequency table to fill in the gaps.

I have no idea how to approach this other than it's a lag/lead thing but the differences are irregular.

Here is my set up below:

```
CREATE TABLE #HighFreq
    (MD INT NOT NULL,
    LOSS float)

INSERT INTO #HighFreq
VALUES
    (6710,0.5)
    ,(6711,0.6)
    ,(6712,0.6)
    ,(6713,0.5)
    ,(6714,0.5)
    ,(6715,0.4)
    ,(6716,0.9)
    ,(6717,0.9)
    ,(6718,0.9)
    ,(6719,1)
    ,(6720,0.8)
    ,(6721,0.9)
    ,(6722,0.7)
    ,(6723,0.7)
    ,(6724,0.7)
    ,(6725,0.7)

CREATE TABLE #LowFreq
    (MD INT NOT NULL
    ,X FLOAT
    ,Y FLOAT)

INSERT INTO #LowFreq
VALUES
    (6710,12,1000)
    ,(6711,8,1001)
    ,(6718,10,1007)
    ,(6724,8,1013)
    ,(6730,11,1028)
```

And I want my output to look like this:

[image: Sample Output]

Comment: I started on an answer then lost interest. It should be clear how to finish it off though if useful https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bf9b65fdec7e40f8c452edf4e5d5bb05

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an approach using a recursive cte and window functions. The recusive cte generates the list of `md`s from values available in both tables. Then, the idea is to put adjacent "missing" `#LowFreq` records into groups, using gaps-and-island technique. You can then do the interpolation in the outer query, by projecting values between the first (and only) non-null value in the group and the next one.

```
with cte as (
    select min(coalesce(h.md, l.md)) md, max(coalesce(h.md, l.md)) md_max
    from #HighFreq h
    full join #LowFreq l on l.md = h.md
    union all
    select md + 1, md_max from cte where md < md_max
)
select
    md,
    loss,
    coalesce(x, min(x) over(partition by grp)
        + (min(lead_x) over(partition by grp) - min(x) over(partition by grp))
        * (row_number() over(partition by grp order by md) - 1) 
        / count(*) over(partition by grp)
    ) x,
    coalesce(y, min(y) over(partition by grp)
        + (min(lead_y) over(partition by grp) - min(y) over(partition by grp))
        * (row_number() over(partition by grp order by md) - 1) 
        / count(*) over(partition by grp)
    ) y
from (
    select 
        c.md,
        h.loss,
        l.x,
        l.y,
        sum(case when l.md is null then 0 else 1 end) over(order by c.md) grp,
        lead(l.x) over(order by c.md) lead_x,
        lead(l.y) over(order by c.md) lead_y
    from cte c
    left join #HighFreq h on h.md = c.md
    left join #LowFreq l  on l.md = c.md
) t
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=11dafc94b38d7705e4c0899b66fdd87c)**:

```
  md | loss |                x |                y
---: | ---: | ---------------: | ---------------:
6710 |  0.5 |               12 |             1000
6711 |  0.6 |                8 |             1001
6712 |  0.6 | 8.28571428571429 | 1001.85714285714
6713 |  0.5 | 8.57142857142857 | 1002.71428571429
6714 |  0.5 | 8.85714285714286 | 1003.57142857143
6715 |  0.4 | 9.14285714285714 | 1004.42857142857
6716 |  0.9 | 9.42857142857143 | 1005.28571428571
6717 |  0.9 | 9.71428571428571 | 1006.14285714286
6718 |  0.9 |               10 |             1007
6719 |    1 | 9.66666666666667 |             1008
6720 |  0.8 | 9.33333333333333 |             1009
6721 |  0.9 |                9 |             1010
6722 |  0.7 | 8.66666666666667 |             1011
6723 |  0.7 | 8.33333333333333 |             1012
6724 |  0.7 |                8 |             1013
6725 |  0.7 |              8.5 |           1015.5
6726 | null |                9 |             1018
6727 | null |              9.5 |           1020.5
6728 | null |               10 |             1023
6729 | null |             10.5 |           1025.5
6730 | null |               11 |             1028
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is helpful.  This is a pretty big dataset with multiple groups - two follow up questions: 1.  Where would I insert the GROUP BY in the CTE, is it after the FULL JOIN and Before the UNION statement?  Also how do I handle the Max Recursion 100  error?

Comment: In actuality there are ~350 sets of these with each set of MD's running up to a max of 15000.  After some searching it looks like the max recursion is 32000, how can I loop through each of the sets to do this?